# Assess Most Used Classes of our Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, appexchange

We have a popular *managed package* on **AppExchange**. Is there any way for us to assess which of our classes and custom objects are used the most by our clients? Does Salesforce or 3rd parties provide any tools to gather such data systematically without having the need to survey our users?

This information will help us understand which of our features have most use; hence, we need to invest most time to ensure they work flawlessly. Also, it would be great to know which if our classes & features are not used so much; hence, we don't prioritize development there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Usage Metrics feature as an ISV to identify most used custom objects and visualforce pages:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/usage_metrics_intro.htm

> Custom objects — the total number of records existing per organization
>   in each custom object. This enables you to track how the usage of that
>   custom object is growing with time in any subscriber organization,
>   which is a reliable indicator of how much it's being utilized

It is not the most user friendly tool though - but you can install a package to help parse the data. But I ended up needing to parse the data myself with some apex to get more detailed insights.

Not sure how you would track Apex Class usage without adding some internal logging of when a customer accessed a class - but you could then maybe use the subscriber-to-LMO part of feature management to pass that data back every night